# Child divs to take the height of the root parent (using flex) regardless of potential top offset

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to get several "blocks" embedded within each other (using flex in this particular case), with the following structure:

- parent (blue in JSFIDDLE)

  - container: margin-top: 32px, (red)

    - row1: orange (150 px height, width: 100%)
    - row2: violet (with: 100%, and take remaining height)

This is illustrated in the following code sample:

[jsfiddle example 1 -- not working](https://jsfiddle.net/q5q989p5/)

I want "ALL EMBEDDED" divs to either have the height that is specified (like 150px for the orange div/row1) or take all the "remaining" available height within its parent container. But as you can see in the jsfiddle, it doesn't work: row2 doesn't have the required height.

I understand it takes the full height only with the parent's height is itself set to 100%. If I do that on `container`, because `margin-top` of container is set to 32px, `container` and `row2` have the height of `parent` and this are drawn over the parent's bottom boundary. This is showed in this fork of the jsfiddle:

[jsfiddle example 1 -- not working either with height:100% on container](https://jsfiddle.net/dkjwys32/)

How can I fix that? What is the right approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 main things here is to remove `height: 100%` from `.board_divider_bottom`, and then add `flex-grow: 1` to it, where `flex-grow: 1` will make it take available space.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

.board_container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 2px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 32px;
  height: calc(100% - 32px);          /*  changed, reduce with margin-top  */
}

.board_divider_top {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}

.board_divider_bottom {
  flex-grow: 1;                     /*  added, fill remaining space  */
  border: 2px solid violet;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="board_container">
    <div class="board_divider_top"></div>
    <div class="board_divider_bottom">I want this to take all the remaining height</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- parent -->
```

Comment: Make sense, thanks a lot I was experiment with flex: 1 indeed and realized I was getting somewhere +1 for showing `calc(100% - 32px)`. I didn't know this existed.